# iOS - Error(s) Integrating IMA3 VAST and DFP ads on the same project

Tags: ios, vast, admob

I'm trying to integrate IMA3 VAST ads into a project already working with adMob.

While compiling I get the following error, as well as a few other duplicates:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GAD_GTMStringEncoding
```

I've tried using the latest of both the AdMob and IMA3 pods:

```
pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK' # 3.4.1
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' # 7.17
```

Any idea?

### UPDATE:

Tried reverting to older IMA3 SDK:

```
  pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK', '3.3.1'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', # 7.17
```

App compiles fine but crashes on start on:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GoogleInteractiveMediaAds.framework/GoogleInteractiveMediaAds
  Referenced from: *REMOVED*
  Reason: image not found
```

### UPDATE2:

As per a [suggestion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ima-sdk/QrwiC1JWyD0/discussion) by a member of the IMA SDK team, I tried the deprecated GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK-For-AdMob. Even though it's deprected and [the docs state](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/ios/v3/history) that it's no longer needed.

```
pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK-For-AdMob' # 3.4.1
```

App still crashing on same error.

### UPDATE3:

A Google engineer named Veer identifying himself as part of the IMA iOS SDK team has responded to my [Google Groups thread about this issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ima-sdk/QrwiC1JWyD0).

He acknowledged the issue and claimed that it was fixed on 3.5. Sadly this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing working for me now is using an old version of the deprecated bundled SDK:

```
pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK-For-AdMob', '3.3.1' # Implicit dependency on AdMob SDK. 3.4.1 causes "library not loaded" crash on start
```

I'll post an update if and when Google sort this mess out.